# Bundle not working in MVC 4.5 empty project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I have created an empty `MVC` project in `VS 2012` , there were no files of Jquery CSS by default so i have copied all the Script and CSS file into my Script file and then i Have download System.Web.Optimization NuGets , after that i have create a bundle in my `BundleConfig.cs` file . the code and reference file file are ok then I render the script in my view like that

```
@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

as only `Scripts.Render()` don't work so i give full name space of the Render Method 
but Still my code is not working in My empty MVC project ,although I tested the same code in my MVC Internet Project which is working fine , I have also tested the `Configuration Debug="false"` , but still my bundle not working and simple jquery file reference is working fine . what i am missing . I think all the problem is in Empty project which is missing some files or code to be written manually.

Comment: Have you configured your bundles? In the global.asax application_start have you used  `BundlesConfigurationTask.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);`

Comment: Have you configured your bundles? In the global.asax application_start have you used  `YourBundlesConfigurationTask.yourRegisterBundlesmethod(BundleTable.Bundles);`

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a Bundle Configuration Class:

```cs
namespace DemoApp
{
    public class BundleConfiguration
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(
                new System.Web.Optimization.ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
                .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js")
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And then, in the global.asax.cs

```cs
DemoApp.BundleConfiguration.RegisterBundles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Comment: I tried to do it since yesterday and it was a pain. Your answer was the most helpful I found :)